# Why isn't align-self aligning my div to the bottom of my flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two equal-height columns and I am trying to get the "Read More" link in each column to sit at the bottom of the column, no matter how much content is in the adjacent column. I am using `align-self: flex-end`, which I think is supposed to selectively align this single child, but it isn't working. It is also important that the div heights are not stretched in any way. That is why I have specified `align-items: flex-start;` and `align-content: flex-start;`.

https://jsfiddle.net/stewx/b2aoksgf/2/

```css
h3,
p {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.more {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  align-self: flex-end; /* Has no effect. I would have expected this to move to the bottom. */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="column">
    <h3>
  Foo
  </h3>
    <p>
      The top of this paragraph should be aligned with the top of the paragraph in the other column.</p>
    <p>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet ullamcorper urna. Donec convallis lorem ut semper ultrices. Integer feugiat sodales leo. Sed non lacus sed nisi semper eleifend. Maecenas ultricies condimentum tempor. Fusce vel aliquet
      magna, nec sollicitudin nunc. Fusce ut facilisis lorem. Vestibulum porttitor vehicula mi, in bibendum ante ultrices sit amet. Nulla at dui tempor, ornare risus eu, lobortis lorem.
    </p>
    <p class="more"><a href="#">Read More (I should be at the bottom of this div!)</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h3>
  Bar
  </h3>
    <p>
      The top of this paragraph should be aligned with the top of the paragraph in the other column.</p>
    <p>
      Vivamus porttitor pharetra eros quis maximus. Sed non blandit justo. Phasellus viverra tellus eu diam tempor pretium. Nam iaculis odio non quam iaculis, sit amet vehicula ipsum scelerisque. Nunc ornare augue quis congue finibus. Curabitur efficitur magna
      a fringilla convallis. Nulla nunc mauris, dignissim sit amet arcu sit amet, pellentesque condimentum sapien.
    </p>

    <p>
      Donec tellus purus, sodales non pellentesque a, accumsan ut orci. Vivamus a tincidunt odio, nec fringilla nulla. Nulla eu metus felis. Vivamus dictum accumsan ante pellentesque dapibus. Donec neque orci, congue pretium leo quis, tempor aliquam justo.
      Sed elementum cursus mauris vel consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam varius, ante in fermentum condimentum, lorem urna vulputate justo, nec maximus lectus leo sodales lectus. In nec orci mollis, varius ante
      id, faucibus ipsum. Etiam auctor a mi semper egestas. Morbi tincidunt at nunc non semper. Sed mattis tellus ex, in consequat leo facilisis id. Vivamus eleifend pellentesque tempus.
    </p>
    <p class="more"> <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: column` and `margin-top: auto` on  `.more`

```css
h3,
p {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.more {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: auto;
  /* Has no effect. I would have expected this to move to the bottom. */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="column">
    <h3>
  Foo
  </h3>
    <p>
      The top of this paragraph should be aligned with the top of the paragraph in the other column.</p>
    <p>

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet ullamcorper urna. Donec convallis lorem ut semper ultrices. Integer feugiat sodales leo. Sed non lacus sed nisi semper eleifend. Maecenas ultricies condimentum tempor. Fusce vel aliquet
      magna, nec sollicitudin nunc. Fusce ut facilisis lorem. Vestibulum porttitor vehicula mi, in bibendum ante ultrices sit amet. Nulla at dui tempor, ornare risus eu, lobortis lorem.
    </p>
    <p class="more"><a href="#">Read More (I should be at the bottom of this div!)</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h3>
  Bar
  </h3>
    <p>
      The top of this paragraph should be aligned with the top of the paragraph in the other column.</p>
    <p>
      Vivamus porttitor pharetra eros quis maximus. Sed non blandit justo. Phasellus viverra tellus eu diam tempor pretium. Nam iaculis odio non quam iaculis, sit amet vehicula ipsum scelerisque. Nunc ornare augue quis congue finibus. Curabitur efficitur magna
      a fringilla convallis. Nulla nunc mauris, dignissim sit amet arcu sit amet, pellentesque condimentum sapien.
    </p>

    <p>
      Donec tellus purus, sodales non pellentesque a, accumsan ut orci. Vivamus a tincidunt odio, nec fringilla nulla. Nulla eu metus felis. Vivamus dictum accumsan ante pellentesque dapibus. Donec neque orci, congue pretium leo quis, tempor aliquam justo.
      Sed elementum cursus mauris vel consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam varius, ante in fermentum condimentum, lorem urna vulputate justo, nec maximus lectus leo sodales lectus. In nec orci mollis, varius ante
      id, faucibus ipsum. Etiam auctor a mi semper egestas. Morbi tincidunt at nunc non semper. Sed mattis tellus ex, in consequat leo facilisis id. Vivamus eleifend pellentesque tempus.
    </p>
    <p class="more"> <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `align-self` property is closely related to `align-items`. One is designed to override the other. Hence, [they both function together](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property).

However, `align-self` and `align-items` work primarily in *single-line flex containers*.

When there are multiple rows of flex items in the cross-axis – like in the question – the property to use is [`align-content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property).

But when `align-content` is in effect, both `align-items` and `align-self` are limited. Remove `align-content` from `.column` and `align-self` works fine.

The most efficient way to achieve your layout (if wrapping rows aren't absolutely necessary) is to switch to `flex-direction: column` and use an `auto` margin on `.more`.

For more details on `auto` margins see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

---

*From the spec:*

> [**8.3. Cross-axis Alignment: the `align-items` and `align-self` properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property)
>
> `align-items` sets the default alignment for all of the flex container’s items, including anonymous flex items. *`align-self` allows this default alignment to be overridden for individual flex items.*
>
> [**8.4. Packing Flex Lines: the `align-content`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property)
>
> The `align-content` property aligns a flex container’s lines within the
>   flex container when there is extra space in the cross-axis, similar to
>   how `justify-content` aligns individual items within the main-axis.
>   *Note, this property has no effect on a single-line flex container.*