# Parent align-content:flex-start; while having one child element flex-end?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm able to align all child elements as `flex-start` like so:

```
.parent{
    display:flex;
    align-content:flex-start;
}
```

But then I have a child element, a one-off that I want to be able to create as a `flex-end`, but doing this won't work:

```
#child2{
    align-self:flex-end;
}
```

What is the reason `child2` won't align as `flex-end`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the reason `child2` won't align as `flex-end`?

My answer here may be enough to answer your question:

- [Why isn't `align-self` aligning my div to the bottom of my flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020587/3597276)

Here's another possible answer:

You haven't specified a `flex-direction` in your code. This means the container will apply the default value: `flex-direction: row`.

This means the *main axis* is horizontal and the *cross axis* is vertical.

The `align-*` properties (`align-content`, `align-items` and `align-self`) control the alignment of flex items on the *cross axis* (vertical, in this case).

So in your code you're saying:

- align my items at the top of the container
- align one item (`#child2`) at the bottom.

Assuming this is what you actually want, you would need to give the container some height. Without a defined height the container defaults to `height: auto`, the height of the content – leaving `align-self` with no where to go.

Then you'll need to consider that `align-self` doesn't work with `align-content`. It only works with `align-items`. ([More details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35020587/3597276))

In case you're actually wanting to align your items along the *main axis* ( horizontally), you would need to use the `justify-content` property. And the items are already `justify-content: flex-start`, because that's a default value.

However, there is no `justify-self` property for the main axis, like there is an `align-self` property for the cross axis. So you would need to use `auto` margins. ([More details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276).)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be, `flex:1` to your **previous child element**

This filled up entier space and move child2 to right

```
#child1{
    flex:1; //
}
```