# Flexbox equal height white space issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with flexbox. When I create equal columns with flex and some of the columns have larger height, then child div with image will get some white space and I don't know where this is coming from.

As you can see from my code the red background in `.card-thumb` there is wrong height. So how to fix that?

Here is my pen: http://codepen.io/woosaj/pen/bZjyRP

```
.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background: rgba(2552,255,255,.1)
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    padding-left: 0.3125rem;
    padding-right: 0.3125rem;
    max-width: 33.33333%;

}

.card {
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    .card-thumb {
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
    }

}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`align-content: stretch`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property).

This means that multiple lines in a flex container will expand to fill the size of the container.

Because your container is `flex-direction: row` and you've enabled `flex-wrap: wrap`, the `align-content` property distributes the wrapped items vertically (along the [*cross-axis*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)).

With the `stretch` default, the div with the red background is expanding relative to its siblings in order to fill the container height. (If you add a background color to all flex items, you'll notice that together they fill the container.)

Instead, use `align-content: flex-start` or `space-between`.

---

**The next problem** you'll face is that `.bottom` no longer respects `align-self: flex-end`.

To tackle that issue, I would recommend switching the container's `flex-direction` to `column` and applying `margin-top: auto` to `.bottom`. More details:

- [Why isn't align-self aligning my div to the bottom of my flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35020265/3597276)
- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)
- [Align an element to bottom with flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31000885/3597276)

Comment: Hey, thanks for that explanation. I used on `.card` `flex-direction: column wrap` and `margin-top: auto` on `.bottom` div as you said, and this is working fine, so i'll stick with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In style `.card` change the `display:flex;` to `flex:1;`. This will help you.

```
body {
    background: #000;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background: rgba(2552,255,255,.1)
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    padding-left: 0.3125rem;
    padding-right: 0.3125rem;
    max-width: 33.33333%;

}

.card {
    background: #fff;
    flex:1;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    .card-thumb {
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
    }

}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is not good, becuase .card must have display: flex; some items inside using align-self.